# How to make ASP.Net MVC Controller Action Async

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await

My desire is to make an MVC controller Action which does long-running i/o operations asynchronous.  My goal is to avoid tying up threads in the ASP.Net thread pool while this long-running method completes.

The Action makes two calls.

The first call is to a 3rd party dll that does not contain any asynchronous methods.  This dll reads from a proprietary database and does fairly complex cpu-bound processing.  It can take up to a couple of seconds to return.

The second call uses the results of the first call as parameters that are passed to a database query using Entity Framework.

Simplified, this is the Action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyActionAsync(arg1, arg2)
{
    var parameters = 3rdPartyComponent.TakesLongTime(arg1, arg2);

    Task<List<MyClass>> genericList = null;

    using (DbContexts.MyDbContext db = new DbContexts.MyDbContext())
        {
          genericList = await db.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>(sql,parameters).ToListAsync();
        }

    return View("MyView", genericList);
}
```

I would like to make the call to 3rdPartyComponent awaitable.  My initial idea was to do this:

```
var parameters = await Task.Run(() => 3rdPartyComponent.TakesLongTime()).ConfigurateAwait(false);
```

but I've read several subject matter experts state categorically that using Task.Run() inside an asp.net MVC Action is counter-productive and should never be done.

3rdPartyComponent is a black box of compiled code, it cannot be altered to add async methods.

Is there any way to make the call to 3rdPartyComponent awaitable, so that the entire Action runs without tying up a thread in the asp.net thread pool?

Comment: *Task.Run() inside an asp.net MVC Action is counter-productive and should never be done*. This isn't true. There are plenty of cases where you may want to to do this. I'm not saying you should do this all the time but if you want to spawn a seperate thread then why not?

Comment: Hey Tom, take a read of this: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html and consider whether or not you're being premature in your optimizations... Unless this is a heavy traffic method, it's certainly possible that this is an unnecessary step. (You'll probably end up using Task.Factory.StartNew so that you can supply a TaskCreationOptions to in order to schedule the work out of the ThreadPool)

Comment: @spender, yes, this is a heavy-traffic method, extremely so.

Comment: The method you show doesn't have anything which can benefit from being async. The two "async" tasks have to run sequentially anyway.

Comment: @liam, I admit ignorance here, my source for that statement is Stephen Cleary, eg http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Comment: @DavidG, I realize making it async will not make it run any faster for the user who is waiting on the web page.  My goal is to avoid blocking a thread in the asp.net thread pool.

Comment: In that scenario it is a bad idea to use a thread. But that doesn't mean it should never be done. Threads in a web app should be used to perform multiple tasks at the same time or as fire and forget threads. Spawning a thread to do the same work that the main process can do (while the main thread waits) is counter productive. You're using twice as many threads for the same task. I believe that's his point.

Comment: Might it be simpler to cache the result of `3rdPartyComponent.TakesLongTime()`?

Comment: Yes, you should do this ^

Comment: @DavidG, I edited my question to show why this is not possible.  arg1 and arg2 are in most cases different for every caller, there is nothing cacheable here.

Comment: What about splitting the action into multiple actions. For example, `MyActionStart` -> schedules the task to be run on a background thread and returns a GUID that the user can use to check the status of that task. `MyActionStatus` -> Allows a user to poll for status changes of a particular GUID. and `MyActionResult` -> Allows a user to retrieve the results for a particular GUID that has finished.

Comment: Well that doesn't mean you can't cache it, it just means you may need to cache more than one variant of it. Either way, running this async still doesn't help you in any way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The first call is to a 3rd party dll that does not contain any asynchronous methods. This dll reads from a proprietary database and does fairly complex cpu-bound processing.
>
> I would like to make the call to 3rdPartyComponent awaitable.
>
> Is there any way to make the call to 3rdPartyComponent awaitable, so that the entire Action runs without tying up a thread in the asp.net thread pool?

The code is already as good as it can get. Neither `Task.Run` nor `Task.Factory.StartNew` will give you any benefit (even if you pass the `LongRunning` flag).

Since the 3rd-party dll does CPU-bound code, it needs a thread. Even if you could modify it, you could only make the db access (I/O work) asynchronous; CPU work is synchronous by definition, and from your description it sounds like the CPU-bound work is the majority of the time.

The entire point about avoiding `Task.Run` (and the even worse `Task.Factory.StartNew`) on ASP.NET is that they cause less efficient behavior. By freeing up the ASP.NET request thread, you're just returning a thread to the thread pool while it's not being used; there's nothing magical or special about the ASP.NET request threads. So `Task.Run` frees up one thread pool thread by switching to another thread pool thread, and `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `LongRunning` frees up a thread pool thread by creating a whole new thread, scheduling the work to that, and then tearing down that thread at the end (this behavior is not documented nor specified, but it is the current observed behavior).

So what you end up doing is just incurring needless thread switches (and in the case of `StartNew`, an entire extra thread). ASP.NET is designed to handle both synchronous and asynchronous work; if you have synchronous code, the best thing to do is just execute it directly, exactly like your code is already doing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'd argue that using `Task.Run` in an async server method is an anti-pattern because the work that you schedule would simply end up being requeued in the ThreadPool, which is exactly the place you just came from... net gain zero (minus the overhead of scheduling a callback in the ThreadPool).

My first thoughts are to fire off the work with

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(action,TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
```

`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` is a hint that the work should be done in a new Thread rather than the ThreadPool.

...but if this is a heavy traffic method, you run the risk of creating threads faster than they clear down and now you've lost the management benefits of the ThreadPool.

If the traffic really is as high as you say and requires this sort of special treatment, some sort of throttling and/or cacheing might be in order... But that would be a different question...

Comment: ...yes you really can spell "cacheing" like that!

Comment: I Google "cacheing" and it tells me "Showing results for caching" :)

Comment: +1 for the TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning hint.  But I think the real answer to this question is "don't try to make this action async, it will create more problems than it fixes."